# ¿Qué hace este comando?

Tags: linux

Necesito saber que hace cada uno de los comandos en la siguiente línea:

```
history > ~/ultimos_comandos.txt
```

Además necesito saber para que sirve dicha línea

Comment: Básicamente el comando ``history`` te muestra el historial de comandos ejecutados en el sistema.  Lo que hace ``history > ~/ultimos_comandos.txt``  es guardar el historial en un archivo de texto en la ruta específicada.

Comment: @Fernando, ¿vas a colocar eso en una respuesta?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vamos por partes:

- **[history](https://ss64.com/bash/history.html)** es un comando que te devuelve un *historial* con cierto número de comandos que se han escrito en el *shell* para el usuario que ejecuta el comando. El número de comandos puede variar de una distribución a otra o de un usuario a otro, según los parámetros de configuración que se explican en la página de manual enlazada. Es decir, al ejecutar `history`, *juan* verá su historial de comandos, y *pedro* el suyo propio.
- `>` el caracter *mayor que*, al aparecer de esta manera en la línea de comandos le indica al intérprete que se desea hacer una *redirección de la salida estándar* hacia un archivo. La salida estándar por defecto es la terminal, así que, en lugar de imprimirse en la terminal lo que sea que genere el comando a ejecutar (en este caso history) se va a *re-dirigir* a *otro lado*
- `~/ultimos_comandos.txt` es un nombre de archivo, y esto completa la instrucción de re-dirección de la salida, ahora sabemos que lo que el comando escriba a la salida estándar se va a escribir al archivo `ultimos_comandos.txt` en la carpeta *home* del usuario, ya que el caracter `~` es un alias de dicha carpeta *home* del usuario, que es usualmente `/home/xxx` donde `xxx` es el *login* del usuario.

Answer (score 0):

Básicamente el comando `history` te muestra el historial de comandos ejecutados en el sistema.

**Ejemplo.** Ejecutamos los comandos `ls`, `cal` y `date`. Obtenemos el historial de los comandos con `history`.

```
$ ls
$ cal
$ date
$ history
```

Lo cual nos mostrará una lista como está:

```
ls
cal
date
history
```

Al ser history el último comando ejecutado también se mostrará.

Lo que hace esta sentencia `history > ~/ultimos_comandos.txt` es guardar el historial en un archivo de texto en la ruta específicada.

Espero que hay aclarado tu duda.